# Como renderizar html dentro de um componente funcional em React?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou usando a versão `16.12.0` do react. Eu possuo um component funcional chamado `Card` e gostaria de inserir html dentro dele (gostaria de não mudar o código fonte dele).

Card:

```
function Card ({cardHeader, cardBody, cardDescription}){

return (
    <>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                <h1>{cardHeader}</h1>
                <p>{cardDescription}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                {cardBody}
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)}
```

E gostaria de passar o html a mais pra dentro desse componente da seguinte forma:

```
 <Card cardHeader={cardTitle} cardBody={object} >
   <div className="card-close">
      ...
   </div>
 </Card>
```

Dessa forma, nos outros lugares que usam o component do card, não vão precisar de adaptações. Alguma idea  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode acessar através da prop [`children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment). Por exemplo:

```js
<Card cardHeader={cardTitle} cardBody={object}>
   <div className="card-close"></div> // Essa div é o "children"
</Card>
```

E no componente `<Card>`:

```js
function Card ({children, cardHeader, cardBody, cardDescription}){
    return (
        <>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h1>{cardHeader}</h1>
                    <p>{cardDescription}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    {cardBody}
                    {children} // Exibe o que foi passado como "children"
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Veja um exemplo prático:

```js
function Componente({ children }) {

  return <div style={{backgroundColor:'red', height: '100px'}}>{children}</div>
}

function Pai() {
  return (
    <Componente>
      <h1>Qualquer HTML</h1>
      <p>Pode ser passado aqui</p>
    </Componente>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Pai />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vc precisa adicionar um HTML externo, certo?

Dá para usar o [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
 <Card cardHeader={cardTitle} cardBody={object} >
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ html: `
      <div className="card-close">
          ...
      </div>
   ` }} />
 </Card>
```